# ASP.NET File uplading:Show Progress to User

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page where i want to use a file uploading facility for the user.in ASP.NET ,we have an ASP.NET File upload control.I want the site to show some upload progress back to the user when he uploads the file to the site.IF i use ASP.NET file upload control,It will use the post back and it will not give the user the impression as youtube/orkut gives while uploading files. Can any one tell me a solution for this ? I am using VS 2008

Answer (score 1):

[How to implement file upload progress bar on web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564/how-to-implement-file-upload-progress-bar-on-web)

and I suggest you read:

[How do I configure IIS to handle really large file uploads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206132/how-do-i-configure-iis-to-handle-really-large-file-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a 'native' .NET control, check out YUI Uploader.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [3rd Party](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti_1.html) tool may be what your looking for