# AsyncFileUpload Change Request Size

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on an ASP.net C# web app. I am using the AjaxControlToolkit ASyncFileUpload, however, when I upload a certain file I get the error message Maximum Request Length Exceeded. Is there a way that I can increase the size limit for file uploads.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AsyncFileUpload file size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597943/asyncfileupload-file-size-limit) Come on @Boardy, did you search at all? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum request length is set in web.config, specifically in the [httpRuntime/maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) value.

```
<!-- Maximum 16 MB -->
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16384" />
```

Do be aware that there might also be a limitation in IIS depending on your version.

Answer (score -1):

Max request length is defined in web.config in KB as 4096 (default to 4MB), you can change the following in web.config

```
   <system.web>

  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200"

  enable = "True"

  executionTimeout="45"/>

  </system.web>

 </configuration>
```